# php/mysql/jquery (broken with simple jquery code)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, templates

I have been trying to create an SPA that signs up a user, stores the user in the database, and then displays the user info in a div. I am using PHP/MYSQL and jQuery. Here is a walk through for the problem:

I got all of the bellow code working; I'll post this first - and then go over what happens when I try and use jQuery.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>it IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="application.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ejs_production.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>it IT</h1>
    <div id="signup">
        <form id="signupform" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="signin"></div>
    <div id="showuser">
        <h2>Username - Email</h2>
        <ul id="listuser"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

insert_ac.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$uname="root"; // Mysql username
$password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$uname", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Get values from form
$username=$_POST['username'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, password, email)VALUES('$username', '$pw', '$email')";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Like I said, all of the above code works fine - a user gets created and the echo works within the if/else statement as it should.

Now - I want to insert a .php file (as a template, basically) into the "listuser" div. This template should display the user's email and username.

Here is the template:

templates/showuser.php

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $uname="root"; // Mysql username
    $password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="itit"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$uname", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");
    $lastuser="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY autoIncrementColumn DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$lastuser) or die (mysql_error());
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>

<li><? echo $row['username'] ?> - <? echo $row['email'] ?></li>

<?php
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Next, I comment out this code (from insert_ac.php):

```
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Here is the jQuery that kind of replaces what I commented out:

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#listuser").load("templates/showuser.php")
        $("#signupform").remove();   
    });
});
```

When I comment out insert_ac.php code, and implement the jQuery - the template gets shown in the listuser div, but the user no longer gets saved, and thus nothing gets displayed in the template (except for the "-" character). Does anyone know why, once I implement the jQuery - the user no longer gets saved?

**UPDATE**

Due to some suggestions, I tried to make my code more secure. Here is what I changed...it seems to be working - a user gets saved - and the printf() statement gets displayed.

insert_ac.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$uname="root"; // Mysql username
$password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$uname", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Get values from form
$username=$_POST['username'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql= $link->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, password, email)VALUES(?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('sss', $username, $pw, $email);
$sql->execute();
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($sql));
mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
//if($result){
//echo "Successful";
//echo "<BR>";
//echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
//}

//else {
//echo "ERROR";
//}
//?>

<?php
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Is this more secure/what I should be doing?

Comment: Can you trim this down to the relevant parts? This is way more than is required. You also **urgently** need to read up on [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) before you suffer from a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Please fix this before you get in serious trouble.

Comment: security issues everywhere! like @tadman said, please read and try work a code little bit more elegant

Comment: cool...just read up - ill update my question and you can tell me if it is secure...for the update...i also commented out application.js so it the jquery wouldnt mess anything up while i tested it. i was just trying to be thorough with my question..what do you consider irrelevant to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was trying to do...here is all my code if anyone wants to try it too!

insert_ac.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$uname="root"; // Mysql username
$password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$uname", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Get values from form
$username=$_POST['username'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql= $link->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, password, email)VALUES(?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('sss', $username, $pw, $email);
$sql->execute();
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($sql));
mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
//if($result){
//echo "Successful";
//echo "<BR>";
//echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
//}

//else {
//echo "ERROR";
//}
//?>

<?php
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>it IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="application.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>it IT</h1>
    <div id="signup">
        <form id="signupform" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="signin"></div>
    <div id="showuser">
        <h2>Username - Email</h2>
        <ul id="listuser"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('insert_ac.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#listuser").load("templates/showuser.php");
            $("#signupform").remove();   
        });
    });
});
```

templates/showuser.php

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $uname="root"; // Mysql username
    $password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="itit"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$uname", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT username, email FROM users ORDER BY autoIncrementColumn DESC LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<li><? echo $row['username'] ?> - <? echo $row['email'] ?></li>

<?php
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are preventing the default in this line

```
e.preventDefault();
```

And never actually posting the file

Try

```
e.preventDefault();
$.post('insert_ac.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
    $("#listuser").load("templates/showuser.php");
    $("#signupform").remove();   
});
```

Comment: hey orange..i am trying to make my code more secure...than i will see if ur response is what i needed...thanks!